# Dropdown list flicker on first click, and pop up opens and closes fast

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, dropdown

I have kendo drop down list at the bottom of my page. The flickering happens only at first click.

```
<select id="TIVSelect" kendo-multi-select ng-if="fieldnameLower == totalSumInsured && isTIVColumnList"  multiple="multiple"
k-template="itemTemplate" k-data-text-field="'FileColumnName'" k-data-value-field="'FileColumnName'" k-filter="'contains'" ng-model="BFCoreFinancialVM.TotalInsurableValue.MappingOptionsColumns"
k-data-source="BFCoreFinancialVM.TotalInsurableValue.ColumnMappingList"
class="m-b form-control" k-on-change="changeMappingOptions(BFCoreFinancialVM.TotalInsurableValue)"
placeholder="'Please select the \'Total Sum Insured\' Column'" />
```

Comment: code please........

Comment: @לבנימלכה Code added

Comment: couldn't reproduce the flickering, please give more details

Answer (score 0):

maybe you use an outdated jQuery version, the flickering was a known issue in older versions, try using a newer one.

you could have problems with jQuery version 1.9.1 and should be fine with the newer versions like 2.2.x / 3.4.1

Comment: I only use Angular.js, and we use the recent